# How to get current server time in JS

Tags: javascript

when I change the time on my laptop or PC, the countdown time also changes, how do I solve the problem with the code below? thank you master.

```
var end_of_time = new Date("2022-01-30 10:00:00").getTime();

var x_user = setInterval(function() {

    var time_now = new Date().getTime();

    var distance = end_of_time - time_now;

    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Remaining " + hours + "h "
    + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";

    if (distance < 0) {
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Expired";
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Where does this code run? It sounds like you're running it in the browser

Comment: Why do you consider this a problem in the first place? It's kinda expected that when a users changes their computer's time, websites will use that new time.

Comment: How do you serve the HTML? Is it generated using node, or some other back-end? You could fetch the server time from an endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't rely on `javascript` for date calculations when you run in the browser.
2. Think of rendering this page from the server side.
3. Or, if you are running an application in the browser (client-side), think of exposing a REST API to get the time from the server and proceed with calculations in UI.